# Text with no spaces breaking line at 150 characters

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-wrap

Given a text with no spaces, how can we flow it without any line breaks.
It seems indesign only allows the line to be 150 characters long.
Can this be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that InDesign regards your text as one long word. Hyphenation won't work because InDesign can only properly hyphenate words in its dictionary and it will add hyphens at the end of each line. And it seems it has a 150 characters limit for non-hyphenated words.

A solution could be to insert a space after each character and apply negative tracking to the text to give the spaces zero width.

Make a text frame like shown below, make a guide that aligns with the second H, select the second paragraph and nudge the tracking until the letters align. (We hope the font designer gave the space a nice round percentage of an em.)

[image]

Here I'm using Consolas and it seems the tracking needed is -275. (Meaning the space in the font is 0.550 em wide.)

Now you need to insert a space after each character in your story. It can be done quickly by using *Edit > Find/Change*.

With your story selected perform the following:

[image]

Set *Find what* to `.` and *Change to* to `$0`  (notice the space in the end) and press *Change All*. (This will change every character to the found character plus a space.)

Now select all the text and set tracking to the found value (in this example -275).

You no longer have the 150 characters limitation.

[image]