# How can I increase the maximum character limit for text along a path in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm attempting to place the first 1000 digits of pi along a circular path, but the text gets truncated. How can I resolve this issue or is there a character limit I should be aware of?

the 1000 digits of pi:

> 

=  3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781
6406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231
7253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109
7566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664
8213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364
3678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919
5309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793
8183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702
7705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713
4275778960917363717872146844090122495343014654958537105079227968925892
3542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998
3729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850
3526193118817101000313783875288658753320838142061717766914730359825349
0428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927
876611195909216420199 ...

that is truncated to:

> =  3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781

Comment: Make the font smaller? Or the circle bigger?

Comment: Illustrator might have a limit on how long words can be. I know InDesign does. See this related question and my answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/160195/84899

Comment: @Wolff adding nonbreaking space could help.

Comment: @joojaa, maybe but in the question I answered the OP actually wanted the text to break so an ordinary space was fine.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad,nope,  i tried both,

Comment: What version are you using. Because i can get all digits in your text on a path. So what gives? Maybe you made the font nonuniform in size?

Comment: Tried a thousan digits (yoru post isnt exactly thousand so i got more form the net)  so heres what i get in illustrator (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLYgG.png)

Comment: @joojaa, oh so Illustrator doesn't have a character limit, but InDesign does? Weird.

Comment: Same here, no problem using three times as many characters. Maybe post some screencaps showing what the problem is?

Comment: @Wolff illustrator does not have an advanced full page paragraph composer so it does not get weirded by results of long words. Besides text on path is just one line

Comment: @joojaa, it seems that Illustrator text frames (and text on path) can only contain 5979 character lines. One more and it shows overset text no matter what. (Must give problems in Finnish sometimes, no?)

Comment: @Wolff Nomuttaeihäntoiolemikäänongelma